Vertical space after display math is too much
I have a beamer document:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools,xcolor,parskip}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%ù%%%%%%%%
\definecolor{fondo}{HTML}{e6e6e6}  % gris claro
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=fondo,fg=black}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\vfill}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\setlength{\parskip}{0.4\baselineskip}}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=0.35cm,text margin right=0.35cm}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parskip}{\fill}

\begin{frame}{Demo}

The transportation problem as it is stated in modern literature looks somewhat different because of the development of Riemannian geometry.

Let $c: X \times Y \rightarrow[0, \infty]$ be a Borelmeasurable function. Given probability measures $\mu$ on $X$ and $\nu$ on $Y$, Monge's formulation of the optimal transportation problem is to find a transport map $T: X \rightarrow Y$ that realizes the infimum
\[
\inf \left\{\int_X c(x, T(x)) \mathrm{d} \mu(x) \mid T_*(\mu)=\nu\right\},
\]

\begin{block}{}
Monge's formulation of the optimal transportation problem can be ill-posed, because sometimes there is no $T$ satisfying $T_*(\mu)=\nu$ : this happens, for example, when $\mu$ is a Dirac measure but $\nu$ is not.
\end{block}{}

\end{frame}

\end{document}


The red segment is longer than the blue segment. Could you elaborate on how to reduce the space after math display by some percentage?

It's not the prettiest, but I use \mode<presentation>{\vspace{-\normalbaselineskip}} whenever I have this problem.

@MatthewLeingang I put your command \mode<presentation>{\vspace{-\normalbaselineskip}} in the preamble but there is no change...

Have you considered replacing \setlength{\parskip}{\fill} with, say, \setlength\parskip{0.5\baselineskip}? This will reduce the vertical skip between paragraphs -- although, admittedly, not between ordinary paragraphs and a block environment.

@Mico I want to use \setlength{\parskip}{\fill} so that the vertical space between paragraphs will dynamically increase. This allows us to make use of the "redundant" space...

@Mico I have edited my thread to make my question clearer.

My hack isn’t intended to be a document-wide change. I use it on individual slides to adjust spacing

If you are sure that \belowdisplay(short)skip primitive registers will not need to be more changed in the document and that you never follows display math by the continuation of the paragraph (i.e. always the empty line or \par follows) then you can do global setting in the preamble:
\belowdisplayskip=0pt \belowdisplayshortskip=0pt
\newskip\belowdisplayskip \let\belowdisplayshortskip=\belowdisplayskip

This trick disables once and for all the access to the primitive values of \belowdisplayskip,  \belowdisplayshortskip by the macros. LaTeX macros (like \normalfont) can do anything but the primitive values are unchanged.

I put your commands in the preamble but there is no change...

@Akira I put these commands in your preamble and there is change.

Please see my screenshot https://i.sstatic.net/M6UBR3Qp.png.

@Akira Try to put \vspace{-\belowdisplayshortskip} instead \vspace{-\belowdisplayskip} in egreg's solution. You get exactly the same result as in your screenshot. egreg has a mistake in his solution, because this paragraph needs correction by \belowdisplayshortskip, no \belowdisplayskip. So, the effect is more visible in egreg's bad solution. But you can see the effect in my solution too. Try to comment out my commands and see the result and try to use my commands and see the result.

You are right! Thank you very much for your elaboration.

You need to remove the vertical spacing that TeX adds after a display, in this case \belowdisplayshortskip (but it could be \belowdisplayskip if the line preceding the display is long in comparison to the equation). The trick is to say
\vspace{-\lastskip}

where you need it.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%ù%%%%%%%%
\definecolor{fondo}{HTML}{e6e6e6}  % gris claro
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=fondo,fg=black}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\vfill}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\setlength{\parskip}{0.4\baselineskip}}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=0.35cm,text margin right=0.35cm}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setlength{\parskip}{\fill}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Demo}

The transportation problem as it is stated in modern literature looks 
somewhat different because of the development of Riemannian geometry.

Let $c: X \times Y \rightarrow[0, \infty]$ be a Borelmeasurable function. 
Given probability measures $\mu$ on $X$ and $\nu$ on $Y$, Monge's 
formulation of the optimal transportation problem is to find a transport 
map $T: X \rightarrow Y$ that realizes the infimum
\[
\inf \left\{\int_X c(x, T(x))\, \mathrm{d} \mu(x) \mid T_*(\mu)=\nu\right\},
\]

\vspace{-\lastskip}

\begin{block}{}
Monge's formulation of the optimal transportation problem can be ill-posed, 
because sometimes there is no $T$ satisfying $T_*(\mu)=\nu$ : this happens, 
for example, when $\mu$ is a Dirac measure but $\nu$ is not.
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}

Notes

use \frametitle, not optional braced arguments
xcolor is already loaded by beamer
parskip does nothing meaningful here
\end{block} doesn't require {}
don't forget the thin space before the differential.


You might think that setting \belowdisplayskip to zero is a good idea. It isn't, as the following example shows: if you want to have text after a display, you'd be doomed.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%ù%%%%%%%%
\definecolor{fondo}{HTML}{e6e6e6}  % gris claro
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=fondo,fg=black}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\vfill}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\setlength{\parskip}{0.4\baselineskip}}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=0.35cm,text margin right=0.35cm}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setlength{\parskip}{\fill}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}
% make the registers unavailable for change
\skipdef\belowdisplayskip=255
\skipdef\belowdisplayshortskip=255


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Demo}

The transportation problem as it is stated in modern literature looks somewhat 
different because of the development of Riemannian geometry.

Let $c: X \times Y \rightarrow[0, \infty]$ be a Borelmeasurable function. Given 
probability measures $\mu$ on $X$ and $\nu$ on $Y$, Monge's formulation of the 
optimal transportation problem is to find a transport map $T: X \rightarrow Y$ 
that realizes the infimum
\[
\inf \left\{\int_X c(x, T(x)) \mathrm{d} \mu(x) \mid T_*(\mu)=\nu\right\},
\]

\begin{block}{}
Monge's formulation of the optimal transportation problem can be ill-posed, 
because sometimes there is no $T$ satisfying $T_*(\mu)=\nu$ : this happens, 
for example, when $\mu$ is a Dirac measure but $\nu$ is not.
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Demo 2}

This frame shows a funny formula
\[
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\]
which people think to be important.

\begin{block}{}
The formula above is not so important, actually
\end{block}

\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Demo 3}

This frame shows a funny formula
\[
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\]

which people think to be important.

\begin{block}{}
The formula above is not so important, actually
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}

The output in the second frame is unacceptable, but leaving a blank line after the display is even worse.


The package parskip is required for \setlength{\parskip}{\fill}, no?

Can we have a "version" of \vspace{-\belowdisplayskip} to put in preamble? In this way, we don't nee to manually insert \vspace{-\belowdisplayskip}, which is quite "intrusive".

@Akira You might set \belowdisplayskip to zero, but this would destroy the spacing if the display is not to be followed by a \fill. I'd simply avoid the style you want.

Due to \setlength{\parskip}{\fill}, I guess (but not sure) the math display is always followed by \fill.

I put \belowdisplayskip = 0pt in the preamble but there is no change.

@Akira \parskip glue is inserted only if a blank line (or \par that can be implicitly supplied, like by block) follows the display. Setting \belowdisplayskip should be done as part of \normalfont.

@Akira You can set the parameters to zero, but, as I show in my edit, you're shooting to your own foot.

You are right. I have abandoned this modification.

@Akira As usual, wipet is rude in his comments. I fixed the method for removing the vertical space, which is independent on the one TeX chooses.
